# Upload video in chunks api call

Tags: node.js, facebook-graph-api

I'm creating a npm module to upload video on the facebook api using chunk upload.
I'm wondering if I should use node stream.
Currently I'm doing it like this:
1. Request api to get the size of chunk.
2. Split the original video in chunks using [unix split cmd](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/split.1.html)
3. Send chunk by chunk.
4. Delete all chunks

I make some tests with streams the output chunks look good.

```
var readable = fs.createReadStream('video.mp4');
var i = 0;
readable.on('readable', () => {
  var chunk;
  while(null !== (chunk = readable.read(1048576))) {
    var fd = fs.openSync('chunk' + i++, 'w');
    fs.writeSync(fd, chunk, 0, chunk.length);
  }
});
```

Should I refactor with Stream ?
Here is a link to the current [git repo](https://github.com/MRdotB/facebook-api-video-upload)
Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The bigger question is "why"? You certainly *could* simply stream this, but should you? If your code works satisfactory now, maybe you shouldn't touch it.

On the other hand, if you use `request-promise`, request already supports streaming - as in `require('fs').readFileStream().pipe(request(options))`; Maybe you can simply stream the video as a whole.

Streaming a file can reduce memory footprint of the whole module, and in certain situations might even finish the upload faster, but really depends on multiple things. Try and see how it goes.

Btw, your example uses writeSync. Why sync? I guess just for testing if it's doing right?

Comment: The sync function was just for testing.  Using a file descriptor looks simpler than stream in my case. Facebook api need a chunk in range [some code](http://pastebin.com/mkQHZHyQ).   I think I can do it with both. What's your opinion ?

Comment: Well, what you have now looks pretty good. I _believe_ with streams it can get more efficient on the runtime-level. Tou would implement a stream that knows how to read and emit only one chunk - basically to count stuff as it reads it and to know from which point to start or stop with actual streaming.
You could then simply `require('my-chunky-stream').getFileStream('./file.mp4').pipe(request(options))`.

Having said that, I *think* the implementation definitely gets more complex and harder to read and maintain. So I would just keep what you have right now, as long as your chunks are small.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the code I used a year ago to upload a video in Node Js using Facebook Graph API:

```
// It publishes the video in chunks to Facebook until it finishes
var publishVideo = function(access_token, text, file) {

  var stats = fs.statSync(file.path);

  var formData = {
    access_token: access_token,
    upload_phase: 'start',
    file_size: stats.size
  };

  // First step, we send the video size
  request.post({ url: 'https://graph-video.facebook.com/v2.3/me/videos', form: formData, json: true },
  function(err, response, body) {
    if (!err) {
      // With the response, we start making the video transfer
      transferProcess(undefined, file, access_token, body, function(err, currentUploadSession) {
        if (!err) {

          var formData = {
            access_token: access_token,
            upload_phase: 'finish',
            upload_session_id: currentUploadSession,
            description: text
          };

          // Once the video transfer ended, we publish the video
          request.post({ url: 'https://graph-video.facebook.com/v2.3/me/videos', form: formData, json: true });
        }
      });
    }
  });
};

// It processes each part of the video until it finishes
var transferProcess = function(uploadSession, file, access_token, body, callback) {

  // First we generate a copy of the file in order to be independent to the original file
  // because it can have problems when opening it at the same time from other file
  var copyFileName = file.path + '-facebook';
  fse.copySync(file.path, copyFileName);

  // Once we have the copy, we open it
  var fd = fs.openSync(copyFileName, 'r');

  var bytesRead, data, bufferLength = 1000000000;
  var buffer = new Buffer(bufferLength);

  var length = body.end_offset - body.start_offset;

  // We read the amount of bytes specified from body.start_offset until length
  bytesRead = fs.readSync(fd, buffer, body.start_offset, length, null);
  data = bytesRead < bufferLength ? buffer.slice(0, bytesRead) : buffer;

  // We generate a file with the recently read data, and with a name of copyFileName-chunked-12313123
  var chunkFileName = copyFileName + '-chunked-' + body.start_offset;

  // We create the file so then we can read it and send it
  fs.writeFile(chunkFileName, data, function(err) {
    if (err) {
      callback(err);
    }
    else {

      var currentUploadSession = uploadSession ? uploadSession : body.upload_session_id;
      var startOffset = parseInt(body.start_offset);

      var formData = {
        upload_phase: 'transfer',
        start_offset: startOffset,
        upload_session_id: currentUploadSession,
        access_token: access_token
      };

      formData.video_file_chunk = fs.createReadStream(chunkFileName);

      // Once we have the file written, we upload it
      request.post({ url: 'https://graph-video.facebook.com/v2.3/me/videos',
      formData: formData, json: true }, function (err, response, body) {
        // If there was an error, we return it
        if (err || body.error) {
          callback(err ? err : body.error, null);
        }
        // If the lecture of the file has ended, facebook will send us the body.start_offset and the body.end_offset,
        // if they are the same, it means that we have ended uploading the video, so we return
        else if (body.start_offset === body.end_offset) {
          callback(err, currentUploadSession);
        }
        // Else, we keep reading the file
        else {
          transferProcess(currentUploadSession, file, access_token, body, callback);
        }
      });
    }
  });
};
```

Hope you can use it.

Joel